# How to wait for the page to fully load?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to webscrape linkedin sales navigator but the page loads other elements only if i scroll down and wait a bit. I tried to execute this a following way but it just added me 3 more elements so I get 6 out of 25.

```
profile_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people?query=(recentSearchParam%3A(doLogHistory%3Atrue)%2Cfilters%3AList((type%3AREGION%2Cvalues%3AList((id%3A102393603%2Ctext%3AAsia%2CselectionType%3AINCLUDED)))))&sessionId=fvwzsZ8CTAKdGri5T5mYZw%3D%3D"

driver.get(profile_url)

time.sleep(20)

action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
to_scroll = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='ember105']")
to_scroll_up = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='ember141']")
action.move_to_element(to_scroll)
action.perform()
time.sleep(3)
action.move_to_element(to_scroll_up)
action.perform()
time.sleep(3)
action.move_to_element(to_scroll)
action.perform()
time.sleep(3)
```

How to solve it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Explicit Wait. As it will make sure the element is visible on UI. You can identify an element that gets loaded after the page is completely loaded and replace `XPATH_of_element` with its XPATH. Also, add this code before extracting the data so it works properly.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'XPATH_of_element')))
```

You can visit this [blog](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load) by Shreya Bose for more information.

Comment: Actually that's not working because the page is loading when you scroll down. And I just cannot make the right code to scroll till the end of the page

Comment: Can you add one or maybe two Screenshots of the page (one of the start and one after the end) as I am unable to navigate it from that link?

Comment: Added, I suppose that the problem occurs because the page consists of two elements, filter and search results tab but I tried to cick on the search results to scroll till the end of the page but it's not working still

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood but if the problem is your script ends before loading the next elements, you can solve this by just adding this before extracting data.
```WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'XPATH_of_25th_element')))```

Comment: The problem actually is that When I scrool to the down of the page by using action.move_to_element I get the same problem because half of the elements that are in the middle of the search results is not loading. So I just cannot get all the elements. Only if I scroll with the delay I get all elements loaded but I can't implement it in code

Comment: Here's a script [link](https://github.com/MbxrAteeq/Web-Scrapping-Projects/blob/main/BMW%20(Selenium)/BMW_scrapper.py) I wrote a year ago for scraping car data and came across the same issue (Pictures were loading only I scrolled them one by one and waited for every single image to load). Let me add some comments for better understanding.